# Don't persist existing datas in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Is there a way to avoid persisting datas with Symfony2? Here is my example:

I have a user and a experience entity with one form. My experience entity is binded with user with `cascade={persist}`. So when a user fill his email address and his experience, both entities are created and binded.

My question is how to avoid to send user informations to the database if his email address already exists?
Here is my function:

```
public function participeAction(Request $request)
{
    $type = new EcoActorsType();
    $form = $this->createForm($type);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $data = $form->getData();

        $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
        $em = $doctrine->getManager();

        $email = $data->getUserActor();
        $email = $email->getEmail();

        $is_email = $em
            ->getRepository('Mobility\PublicBundle\Entity\UserActor')
            ->findOneBy(array(
                'email' => $email
            ));

        if ($is_email == null)
        {
            $em->persist($data);
            $em->flush();
        }
        else
        {
            ????
        }

        $url = $this->generateUrl('public.frontpages.participe');
        return $this->redirect($url);
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

Here is my data object:

```
object(Mobility\PublicBundle\Entity\EcoActors)[905]
    private 'id' => null
    private 'title' => string 'test experience' (length=15)
    private 'type' => int 0
    private 'start' => string 'test start' (length=10)
    private 'arrival' => string 'test arrival' (length=12)
    private 'description' => string 'test test test' (length=14)
    private 'game' => boolean false
    private 'useractor' => 
        object(Mobility\PublicBundle\Entity\UserActor)[898]
            private 'id' => null
            private 'email' => string 'test@test.fr' (length=12)
            private 'ges' => int 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally it was simple. I just setted the object with the one which was already in the data base.
Here is the new code:

```
public function participeAction(Request $request)
{
    $type = new EcoActorsType();
    $form = $this->createForm($type);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid())
{
    $data = $form->getData();

    $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();

    $email = $data->getUserActor();
    $email = $email->getEmail();

    $is_email = $em
        ->getRepository('Mobility\PublicBundle\Entity\UserActor')
        ->findOneBy(array(
            'email' => $email
        ));

    if ($is_email == null)
    {
        $em->persist($data);
        $em->flush();
    }
    else
    {
        $data->setUseractor($is_email);
        $em->persist($data);
        $em->flush();
    }

    $url = $this->generateUrl('public.frontpages.participe');
    return $this->redirect($url);
}

return array(
    'form' => $form->createView()
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
$existingUser = $em->getRepository( "you entity shortname AcmeBundle:Entity" )->findOneByEmail( $email );

if ( $existingUser !== null ) 
{
  //User exists
}else
{
  //User doesn't exist

}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the database integrity side, you can use the [`@UniqueConstraint`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint) to have the schema assign the column as unique.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="UserActor",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="email_idx", columns={"email"})})
 */
class UserActor
{
    // ...
}
```

On the Controller side, you use the `findOneBy` helper functions with Doctrine (the default repository class will generate special find functions for each column in your Entity, such as `findOneByEmail`)

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MobilityPublicBundle:UserActor')->findOneByEmail($email);
if ($user) {
    // User exists
} else {
    // User doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Adding a constraint is okay, but it will generate an Exception if email already exists, it's not nice for the enduser

Comment: @Charles-AntoineFournel Of course - it's up to the dev to handle the exceptions in a user-friendly manner. The ideal approach would be to use both of the above methods.

Comment: I don't want to check if a user exists. This step is ok. I would like to take off my user object if a user exists and juste send the experience in my database.

Comment: @geopl The reason why no one was able to help you is because you didn't convey your problem accurately. "juste send the experience in my database" makes no sense in English. The solution you landed on is in fact simple and well-documented too.